# Combine multiple different discriminating unions

Tags: typescript

Let's say I have 2 different discriminated unions and 2 functions to work with them:

```js
type T1M1 = {
    type: "m1"
}

type T1M2 = {
    type: "m2"
}

type T2M1 = {
    event: "e1"
}

type T2M2 = {
    event: "e2"
}

type Union1 = T1M1 | T1M2;
type Union2 = T2M1 | T2M2;

function f1<T extends Union1["type"], E extends Extract<Union1, { type:T }>> (
    type: T,
    element: E
) {}

function f2<T extends Union2["event"], E extends Extract<Union2, { type:T }>> (
    type: T,
    element: E
) {}
```

Is there a way to combine `f1` and `f2` into one single declaration?

Comment: You mean overloads?

Comment: TS doesn't have partial type argument inference so you can't make a single function `f<U, K, T, E>` where `U` and `K` are the manually specified union type and the discriminant key type, and where `T` and `E` are inferred from the function call.  The common approach to such things is currying, so you have `f<U, K>()` which returns another function... that is, `f` is a factory for `f1` and `f2`, as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/wXgMLW). Does that fully address the question? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?